# Map array of objects using a dictionary, failing in servicenow custom scripting with unexpected token >

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, mapping

```
data = [{"a1":"av1", "b1":"bv1", "c1":"cv1" },     {"a1":"av1", "b2":"bv2", "c2":"cv2" },     {"a1":"av1", "b3":"bv3", "c3":"cv3" },     {"a1":"av1", "b4":"bv4", "c4":"cv4" },     {"a1":"av1", "b5":"bv5", "c5":"cv5" }, ........]
```

Need output like : `{"bv1": "cv1", "bv3":"cv3", , "bv5":"cv5"}`

My data is too big to process. instead of reading all key values any way to get specific key values from data?

I tried with creating a mapping like

```
mapper = {     "bv1" : "keyofb1",     "bv3" : "keyofb3",     "bv5" : "keyofb5"}
```

to get output like : `{"keyofb1": "cv1", "keyofb3":"cv3", , "keyofb5":"cv5"}`

tried with

```
dict = data.map((item) => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(item).map(([key, value]) => [mapper[key], value])));
```

```
error :
Parsing error: Unexpected token \>
```

Comment: this might be the package you want to read your data as a stream - https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-json

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```js
data = [{ "a1": "av1", "b1": "bv1", "c1": "cv1" }, { "a1": "av1", "b2": "bv2", "c2": "cv2" }, { "a1": "av1", "b3": "bv3", "c3": "cv3" }, { "a1": "av1", "b4": "bv4", "c4": "cv4" }, { "a1": "av1", "b5": "bv5", "c5": "cv5" }];

newData = data.map((obj, index) => {
  index++;
  let newKey = obj[`b${index}`];
  let newValue = obj[`c${index}`];
  return { [newKey]: newValue };
});

console.log(newData);
```

1. Basically you can pass the `index` along with `obj` into the `map`
   function
2. Increment since key's start from 1
3. Get the new key,value pair
4. Create the new object